Rendering file from Mongo using Multer not working in AWS Lambda
I am trying to display pdf files from MongoDB using Multer. I am rendering the pdf in my react app.
When I run it locally (express app), it is working perfectly fine. However when I use the AWS Lambda hosted API link, it only displays the name of PDF, and renders a blank PDF:
Do I need to install any other dependency for AWS Lambda?
I dont want to use S3, or any other AWS storage.
This is my resume Schema
const resumeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  data: Buffer,
  contentType: String,
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
});

This is the response I am sending after finding the document:

res.setHeader("Content-Type", matchedResume.contentType);
res.setHeader(
      "Content-Disposition",
      `inline; filename="${matchedResume.name}"`
    );

res.status(200).send(matchedResume.data);


This is how I am rendering the pdf in react app:
onClick={() => {
                const config = {
                  method: "get",
                  headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                  },
                  url: `http://localhost:8257/user/resume/resumes?rId=${props.resume.rId}`,
                  responseType: "blob",
                };
                axios(config)
                  .then((res) => {
                    const blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(
                      new Blob([res.data], { type: "application/pdf" })
                    );
                    // Open the blob URL in a new tab
                    window.open(blobUrl, "_blank");
                  })
                  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
              }}

